# Magento 2.0.9: - Cannot login to magento admin

Tags: magento-2.0, admin-panel

I logged in to `magento 2.0.9 admin`, enabled the caches , but after sometime when refreshed admin panel is not working. Showing like the below.

How to get into the admin panel ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Clean Cache `bin/magento cache:clean`
2. Remove generate files `rm var/generation/* -R`
3. Run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
4. Run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

If you still see this issue, please check magento log and Apache/nginx log and let me know the detail.